# Que signifie "susuque" ?

Tags: sens

Bonjour,

Dans *Le pont de Londres* :

> Tu crois pas que c'est arrivé dis des fois lardon? que tu vas te
> rouler au **susuque**, comme ça jusqu'à la Saint-Glingin?

Dans *Les Beaux Draps* :

> .... *because* les chemins de fer qui déconnent, qui trouvent plus à
> se réchauffer... et le **susuque** qu'est du Nord qui veut plus
> descendre...

Savez-vous ce que signifie "susuque" ? Est-ce que le mot a le même sens dans les citations ci-dessus ?

Comment: sucre ? « Oh, ça c'est mon toutou qui veut un susuc » Ça pourrait coller au moins pour la première citation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Je pense qu'il s'agit du mot « sucre », *susuc* étant un terme très familier pour désigner un morceau de sucre (en général [destiné à son chien](https://jaimelesmots.com/susuc-susuc-medor-ou-susuc-sultan/)).

Dans la première occurrence, je comprends « se rouler au sucre » comme se rouler dans quelque chose de sucré, se faire plaisir. Il ne faut pas exclure ici qu'en écrivant ça Céline n'ait pas voulu jouer sur les mots et vouloir faire penser le lecteur à l'expression « se vautrer dans le stupre<sup>1</sup> », ce qui passerait bien dans le contexte.

Et dans la deuxième occurrence dont voici le contexte complet :

> vu la rareté des transports… les pénuries d’arrivages, le hic des médicaments… le lolo qui vient plus du tout… because les chemins de fer qui déconnent, qui trouvent plus à se réchauffer… et le susuque qu’est du Nord qui veut plus descendre… et les beubeurres qui sont à l’Ouest qui veulent plus entendre rien,

on a le sucre qui ne peut plus arriver du nord, le nord de la France étant la région où la culture de la betterave à sucre et la production de sucre sont le plus développées (et l'étaient déjà du bien avant l'époque de Céline) et le beurre qui ne peut pas arriver de l'ouest, la Normandie, région de l'ouest de la France, étant par tradition une région de production du beurre en France.

<sup><sup>1</sup> [Stupre](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/stupre).</sup>

Comment: Merci beaucoup !